# How to make a Nexus 4 a wifi access point / repeater without using mobile data

Tags: nexus-4, wifi-hotspot

I have a spare Nexus 4 phone after recently upgrading to a Nexus 5. I would like to root the device and use it to share a wifi connection. To be clear, I am not talking about the stock android wifi hotspot functionality which shares a mobile 3G/ 4G data connection wirelessly. I would like to connect to a wifi hotspot from the device and then share that wifi connection to other devices, creating a WLAN. So wifi in, wifi out.

1. Does the Nexus 4 support this?
2. Can it be done without rooting / installing a custom rom?
3. If not, what ROM / apps do people recommend?

Comment: @DanHulme not really, my question is specifically about the nexus 4 and the landscape has changed since 2011

Comment: I don't think this will be possible really. And it's not going to be device specific solution (if any)

Comment: [How to use Android device as router without cellular connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215514/218526)