# How to run hostapd on Redmi 8

Tags: root-access, wifi-hotspot, android-10, hostapd

I have been trying to run the hostapd with my own hostapd.conf but it's refusing to work and keeps saying `segmentation fault` and I am wondering how to get it working on `Redmi 8 running Android 10`

I have been testing everything and it always ends up with the same error

The hostapd it self is located at `/vendor/bin/hw/hostapd`
and also here is the default config from `/data/vendor/wifi/hostapd`

```
max_num_sta=1
vendor_elements=dd0411223301
ssid2=776e3133
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=
acs_exclude_dfs=0
channel=11
ht_capab=[SHORT-GI-20] [GF] [DSSS_CCK-40] [LSIG-TXOP-PROT]
vht_oper_chwidth=0
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
interface=wlan0
ctrl_interface=/data/vendor/wifi/hostapd/ctrl
ieee80211ac=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wowlan_triggers=any
accept_mac_file=/data/vendor/wifi/hostapd/hostapd.accept
deny_mac_file=/data/vendor/wifi/hostapd/hostapd.deny
```

also from what i noticed that file always gets generated when I enable hotspot.

Comment: Android's `hostapd` is somewhat limited. Try a fully custom built binary. Download link is available in my answer to this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215514/218526

Comment: @IrfanLatif it didn't work you sure there isn't a way to get the original bin to work since android is already using it when i enable hotspot

Comment: I can't remember exactly but some time ago, a year or so, the Android binary didn't work for me. So I checked the AOSP source code and some features (which were not used in Android) were disabled at compile time. Then I compiled my own binary, and that worked. But I can't remember exactly what I was trying to do. You've to do some experiments with it. Segfault is a general failure. Narrow down the cause of failure. Use `strace`, check logs, SELinux, capabilities, etc.

Comment: Oh I see thanks well will do as soon as i get the chance to do so